# Creating object with belongs_to association, Validation failed: Class must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby on rails and learning it by building a website, but I've been stuck on this particular problem for quite a while.

In my setup, I have 2 models:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user#, foreign_key: "owner_id", primary_key: "user_id", class_name "User"
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects#, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "projects", primary_key: "project_id"
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

But I keep running into problems when I try to create a project, specifically in the following method

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @user.projects.create!(project_params)
  end
```

It gave me the `Validation failed:  User must exist` error.  I can confirm that user does exist, it's in the database and the controller has `before_action :authenticate_user!`, and when I do `puts @user.attributes` it shows the details correctly.

If possible I really don't want to use the `optional: true` for the belongs_to association, because it doesn't really make sense for a project to be created without an owner, unless it's the standard way to handle the problem. Any guidance on how the create method should be would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you add `devise_for` in your routes? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise please find in here `current_user` and look at the example

Comment: @noname thanks for the comment! yes it's in my routes.rb, and when I do ```puts @users.attributes``` in the create method it shows correctly, so I'd assume user does exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Belongs to associations being required by default is a relatively new and unpopular change and I can say as a Rails veteran, you might just want to disable that while you're learning.  If you want to do that globally you can throw this in your application.rb

`config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false`

As far as the code in your controller goes though... Try this!

```
 def create
   @project = Project.new(project_params)
   @project.user_id = current_user.id

   # assuming you used scaffolding, these paths will work
   # you can render/redirect anywhere you want after creating a project though
   if @project.save
     redirect_to @project
   else
     redirect_to new_project_path
   end

 end
```

Comment: You could likely also combine the first two lines into `@project = Project.new(project_params, user_id: current_user.id)` Haven't tried it but I'm pretty sure it would be fine.

Comment: I see, I had it done this way originally and it had worked, but I wanted to see and learn if there's a way to cope with belongs_to being required. if I can't find a solution and give up, I'll choose this as the accepted answer, thanks a lot for the advice!

Comment: Did you try the new controller action?  That's likely to solve your problem without changing anything about belongs_to.

Comment: ah sorry, I must have misunderstood the post when I first read. it worked wonderfully :D do you have any idea why why would this work but not mine? regardless, thanks a lot!!